# Dynamic models to default value

Tags: ember.js

I have a model that represents an activity. Activities have several standard properties like "start_time", "type", "sub_type", etc. but then each type of type/sub-type will have a set of properties that can be set and a user might want to extend this set so in essence there are a LOT of possibly properties.

I would be ok with -- at least for now -- setting the standard properties explicitly with the `DS.attr(type)` command but would like to have all undefined properties be associated with `DS.attr("string")`. Is this possible?

Here's a simple example:

```
App.Activity = DS.Model.extend({
     type: DS.attr("string"),
     sub_type: DS.attr("string"),
     name: DS.attr("string"),
     description: DS.attr("string"),
     is_private: DS.attr("boolean"),
     start_time: DS.attr("datetime"),
     end_time: DS.attr("datetime"),
     icon: DS.attr("string")
});
```

Where the data coming in could look something like this:

```
{
  "id" : "1",
  "type": "exercise",
  "sub_type": "running",
  "name": "Went Running",
  "description" : "Went for a 7 mile run.",
  "is_private" : false,
  "start_time" : "2013-07-09 08:00:06",
  "end_time" : "2013-07-09 09:05:00",
  "icon": "run",

  "distance" : 7,
  "caloric_burn" : "950"
},
{
  "id" : "2",
  "type": "food",
  "sub_type": "eating",
  "name": "Ate Lunch",
  "description": "Ate lunch at home.",
  "is_private" : false,
  "start_time" : "2013-07-09 12:15:08",
  "end_time" : "2013-07-09 13:05:00",
  "icon": "food",

  "caloric_intake" : "825",
  "qual_healthiness" : "5",
  "qual_enjoyment" : "9"
},
```

As stated above, I'd want non-standard attributes like "caloric_burn" to be associated with the default type of *string*. In the "next version" what I'd really like is to look up the "type" using a **Marker** API endpoint but I'd be happy to solve this simplification first.

---- UPDATE ----

The **Marker** API provides meta/reference information only. So for instance you would get the following from a sideload of Markers from the above Activities:

```
markers: [
          {
               "id": "distance"
               "insight": "marker",
               "typing": "number",
               "uom_context": "length",
               "min-value": 0
          },
               "id": "caloric_burn",
               "insight": "marker",
               "typing": "number",
               "uom_context": "energy",
               "min-value": 0
          },
          {
               "id": "caloric_intake"
               "insight": "marker",
               "typing": "number",
               "uom_context": "energy",
               "min-value": 0
          },
          {
               "id": "qual_healthiness",
               "insight": "static-choice",
               "choices": "healthyness-scale",
               "typing": "number",
               "min-value": 0,
               "max-value": 10
          }
 ]
```

The problem is there could be hundreds (even thousands) of different markers that could **potentially** be included and I don't want to define them all (and that's before users customisations come into play). In practice, for any given transaction, there is actually only a few markers that need to be added to the static definition of Activity. I'd like to be able to identify during the serialisation of the object which properties are not matched in the model and then have them added dynamically.

Comment: is there any attribute in that json that tells you about the extra fields? would `type` and `sub_type` play a role on that? If yes, I would create a base model for the common fields, then create models extending your base models for each scenario (as long as it's not a super large range of possibilities) and then play with adapter & serializer to use each model type for each payload (or part of the payload)

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe that's a good suggestion but unfortunately type/sub-type would only "suggest" more strongly the attributes. It's pretty dynamic although there is a dynamic way to discern type information it would be by calling the Marker API but that would require the model be dynamically changed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the attributes of a model in ember-data. Without this it has no means of doing the dirty checking, among other things.

You could extend the `RESTAdapter` to something like this, but it will be a like breaking new ground. :)

In the adapter, When loading of a record is complete you can check the attributes against the corresponding model and it's declared attributes. If it finds an undeclared attribute, you reopen the class with `App.Activity.reopen`, add in the attribute and repeat for additional attributes.

But, if possible go back to the api and figure out a way to describe all attributes as another Model, like `ActivityAttribute` via a many-to-many relation with Activity.

### Edit: ActivityAttribute expanded on.

Instead of the Activity model with many secondary properties like `start_time`, `end_time`, `caloric_burn` that may be optional.

Activity hasMany Marker.
Marker belongsTo Activity.

The corresponding json with sideloading would be,

```
{
  "activities": [
    "id": 1,
    "type": "exercise",
    // other basic properties

    "marker_ids": [
      1, 2, 3, 4
    ]
  ],
  "markers": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "start_time"          , "value ": "foo" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "end_time"            , "value ": "foo" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "caloric_burn"        , "value ": "foo" },
    { "id": 4, "name": "food_caloric_intake" , "value ": "foo" },
  ]
}
```

Or with embedded records would be,

```
{
  "activities": [
    "id": 1,
    "type": "exercise",
    // other basic properties

    "markers": [
      { "id": 1, "name": "start_time"          , "value ": "foo" },
      { "id": 2, "name": "end_time"            , "value ": "foo" },
      { "id": 3, "name": "caloric_burn"        , "value ": "foo" },
      { "id": 4, "name": "food_caloric_intake" , "value ": "foo" },
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe I could get away with it by having a "details" attribute which I define as type "object" using `registerTransform`. The details attribute would then be a name-value dictionary of all non-standard attributes ... is that a hack or reasonable?

Comment: Although I'm more inclined to go with your `App.Activity.reopen` suggestion. How do I hook into the loading of records so that I can perform the reopen?

Comment: Although maybe if I understood your many-to-many approach better I'd prefer that. There is a good "meta-model" available through the API which allows for me to perform a `GET /marker/[:user_id]/[marker]` or `GET /markers/[:user_id]` for all markers for a given user. This will tell me what "type" the marker is, what unit-of-measure, and other meta-characteristics.

Comment: I think the `Marker` is the same as your `ActivityAttribute` but I'd see that as a *way* of implementing the `App.Activity.reopen` approach  and not the many-to-many approach.

Comment: I've updated my answer with clarification. For [RESTAdapter](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js) you need to get into the source code, docs are slim at the moment.

Comment: thanks for your help so far. I understand your idea but unfortunately the "markers" don't have transactional data (aka, no "value"), only reference/meta data. I've updated my question to give greater clarity about what it looks like. Any thoughts you may have would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I see. You will have the same problem since markers appear to have the same need for optional attributes. You are probably better off without ember-data then, unless you are ok to write your own adapter for it.

Comment: What do you think about a solution along these lines: https://coderwall.com/p/hi6hya

Comment: That could work. It's doing the same `reopen` trick using mixins.